# Submit data with dynamically added partial view to the controller using ViewModels not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, begincollectionitem

I'm adding dynamically items to an Enquiry form. Used partial view to for adding/deleting the items but while submitting the main view the values are not bound. My question is how to do the same.

Have checked couple of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654597/retrieving-values-from-partial-view-during-post-method) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700557/mvc-5-dynamic-rows-with-begincollectionitem) But could not find what's missing .

Using 2 ViewModels , for Main View ( Enquiry) and for partial view ( LineItems) and used BeginCollectionItem for dynamically adding items.

Code:

ViewModels

```
public class EnquiryVM
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string EnquiryNumber { get; set; }
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Clients { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public List<EnquiryLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }

    }
 public class EnquiryLineItemVM
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ManufacturerList { get; set; }
    }
```

Views :
Main:

```
@model ViewModel.EnquiryVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Enquiries", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnquiryNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnquiryNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnquiryNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>





        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientID, "Client", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.ClientID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Clients, "--Select--")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

         <div id="LineItems">
          //  @using (Html.BeginForm()) // do we require again here since this will be like nested form? tested commenting still not working
           // {
                <div id="editorRowsLineitems">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.LineItems)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("_CreateEnquiryItem", item)
                    }
                </div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Add Items", "CreateLineItem", null, new { id = "addItem", @class = "button" });
          //  }
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#addItem').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateLineItem")',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#editorRowsLineitems").append(html);

                        $("form").removeData("validator");
                        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        $('#editorRowsLineitems').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
                $(this).closest('.editorRow').remove();
            });
        $('form').data('validator', null);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
    });


</script>
}
```

partial view :

```
@model ViewModels.EnquiryLineItemVM

<div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ItemList"))
    {
        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ItemDesc)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity)

                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManufacturerId, Model.ManufacturerList, "--Please Select--")

                </td>
                <td>

                    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    }
```

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var viewModel = GetAllCategories();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
  private EnquiryVM GetAllCategories()
        {
            var model = new EnquiryVM();
            var clients = db.Clients.ToList();
            model.Clients = clients.Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.ID.ToString(),
                Text = s.Name
            });

            var LineItems = new List<EnquiryLineItem>();
            model.LineItems = LineItems;

           return model;
        }
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create( EnquiryVM enquiryVM)
        {
            var enquiry = new Enquiry();
            enquiry.EnquiryNumber = enquiryVM.EnquiryNumber;
            enquiry.ClientID = enquiryVM.ClientID;
            enquiry.EnquiryLineItems = enquiryVM.LineItems; //line items are null
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Enquiries.Add(enquiry);
                enquiryVM.ID = enquiry.ID;
                foreach (var item in enquiry.EnquiryLineItems)
                {
                    item.EnquiryID = enquiryVM.ID;
                    db.EnquiryLineItems.Add(item);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            var viewModel = GetAllCategories();
            return View(enquiryVM);
        }
```

How shall I map the dynamically added row's values to the ViewModel ( EnquiryVM ) so that I can insert it into the DB.
Thanks for your patience and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your collection property is `LineItems`, therefore your code to generate its controls needs to be

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("LineItems")) // not ..("ItemList")
{
    ....
}
```

so that it generates inputs with `name="LineItems[xxxx].ItemDesc"` etc, rather than your current use which generates `name="ItemList[xxxx].ItemDesc"` (where `xxxx` is the `Guid`)

As a side note, the code in your POST method will throw an exception if `ModelState` is invalid because you return the view and have not repopulated the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Clients` property. Refer [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) for a detailed explanation.

In addition, the final 2 lines of your script to add items (`$('form').data('validator', null); $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));` should be removed (reparsing the validator is expensive and your doing it twice - once before you add the html (the 2 lines above) and once after you add the html

Comment: Thanks Stephen . Now I got what you were trying to point out regarding the collection property in previous question. I only changed it one place but forgot to match with the property name since was not knowing how internally it works. But your explanation helped to know how the BCI works and how it applies.

Comment: I'll get around to answering your other question soon (hopefully) :)

Comment: can you please let me know how I need to change the reparsing form. I had added reparsing as you advised previously to make the Validation work for Partial View

Comment: Yes , you can expect my next question in a while ;-)

Comment: The code you have inside `success: function (html) {` is correct - it re-parses the validator after you add the html. But the last 2 lines of that script where you repeat it is pointless - those lines of code are executed before the html is returned by the ajax call (ajax is async)

Comment: one more thing to ask you is the Validation fires for all the Item fields , where as one field is not mandatory field. How to exclude that particular field( dropdown ) from being validated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154772/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user2695433).